# Why does a html div tag with a p tag inside it sit differently than one with an img tag inside it?

Tags: html, css, spacing, paragraph

I've written the following code while working on Codecademy.com. Basically I've got a bunch of circle containers created with `<div>` tags. All the containers just sit in a neat row when empty. When I added images inside some of the `<div>`s, it didn't affect the spacing. However, when I added text within a `<p>` tag inside one of the `<div>` containers it bumped the whole container down half an inch. (Note: Remove or adding more `<br>` tags doesn't help, nor did setting the margin to 0.)

My question is: why does this happen and how can I stop it from happening?

Since I'm doing this to learn I'm definitely more concerned with understanding why this is happening than simply getting a quick work-around. Thank you.

Here's the code:

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 5px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.friend {
  border: 2px dashed #008000;
}
.family {
  border: 2px dashed #0000ff;
}
.enemy {
  border: 2px dashed #ff0000;
}
#best_friend {
  border: 4px solid #00c957;
}
#archnemesis {
  border: 4px solid #cc0000;
}
img {
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
div p {
  text-align: center;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
  <title>My Social Network</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="friend" id="best_friend">
    <img src="http://www.smashbros.com/images/og/link.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="friend">
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9e/Navi_oOot.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="family">
    <img src="http://fc07.deviantart.net/fs70/i/2011/196/c/a/deku_tree_manip_by_thegeminisage-d3u262q.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="family">
    <br>
    <p>Forest elf guy number 7</p>
  </div>
  <div class="enemy" id="archnemesis">
    <img src="#" />
  </div>
  <div class="enemy">
    <img src="#" />
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this, you would change the `vertical-align` property to a value other than the default, which is `baseline`.

In this case, the following would work:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/tt5fgs6t/)

```
div {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    /* other styling.. */
}
```

As for the reason *why* the element was sitting lower than the other ones, it's because the text was being aligned with the baseline of the sibling elements. Notice that if you [remove the text](http://jsfiddle.net/krj47e10/), the issue no longer occurs. Since the element is `inline-block`, changing the `vertical-align` property will have an effect on it. If the element was floated, on the other hand, you wouldn't be seeing the issue either.

Comment: Thank you Josh! That totally fixed my problem and helped me understand the reasons behind it! You rock.

Answer (score 0):

because there's something call urgent style sheet, that's giving for original tags such as `<p> or <a> or <html> or <h1>` ect.....
and the `<p>` is always giving the text space.

so the best solution for you is to insert a style for the `<p>`
if you are having issues with the position, you can use `padding , margin,` plus you resize is as you want, it's a new style